# Adding TextViews dynamincally to HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to programatically add a whole bunch of textViews to an already present LinearLayout, which already contains some textviews. The textviews to be added dynamically should be placed to the right of already present textviews in the LinearLayout, thus going beyond the screen area.

But when I add the textviews dynamically the width occupied by already present textviews decreases so as to accomodate the dynamically added one which isn't required. Is there a way so that already present textviews keep occupying the same area and dynamic ones are added beyond the screen.

Some basic code:

XML file

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<FrameLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mediaapp.prototypingcanvas.LaunchFragment"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ll">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Action"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SurveyID"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Status"

            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CreatedOn"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Version"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The corresponding JAVA code is:

```
ll = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.ll);
            lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lparams.setMargins(5,0,5,0);
            for (int i = 0; i <WebRepo.headerListToBeShown.length; i++) {

                TextView tv = new TextView(context);
                tv.setText(WebRepo.headerListToBeShown[i].toString().toUpperCase());
                tv.setId(Integer.parseInt(i +"1"));
                tv.setX();

                tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);


                // li.addView(tv);
                ll.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Use horizontal listview that each item has textview.

Comment: @Ali can u please elaborate a little bit

Answer (score 1):

You should use ListView, and make the listview's oriantion as horizontal.
ListView is list of items that can change dynamically.

Search about using horizontal listview in Google.

Answer (score 0):

works fine with me.. you can add arraylist which contain text to horizontal list view

https://guides.codepath.com/android/implementing-a-horizontal-listview-guide

Comment: I don't prefer using a third-party library.